# Getting PlatformNotSupportedException from 32Feet.NET using Mono under Linux

Tags: linux, bluetooth, mono, 32feet

I am trying to port my Windows service to Linux using Mono. The service uses Bluetooth 32feet.NET library.

I have read [this post](https://32feet.codeplex.com/discussions/430065) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11416160/setting-up-32feet-library) and I tried installing those libraries to my PC:

> mono-runtime mono-xbuild mono-devel mono-gmcs libbluetooth-dev

but I couldn't install `mono-gmcs` since Mono 4 uses `mono-mcs`. I imported `ExternalLibs/Mono etc/NDesk.DBus.dll` to my project's debug folder and solved the `System.DllNotFoundException: BsSDK` exception. Buy I still couldn't figured out why I am getting

> Unhandled Exception: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: No
>   supported Bluetooth protocol stack found.

I tried to [patch](https://bugzilla.novell.com/show_bug.cgi?id=655153) Mono. But I couldn't do it, is there anyone who could got this library work under Linux using Mono?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right path.  It depends largely on [if you're doing it against blueZ](http://blog.mrgibbs.io/pebblesharp-bluez4/) 4 (which 32feet supports) or [blueZ 5](http://blog.mrgibbs.io/get-on-d-bus/) (which 32 feet does not support yet, but [mono.bluez](https://github.com/brookpatten/Mono.BlueZ) does)

[Here's a full set of steps for bluez4](https://github.com/brookpatten/PebbleSharp/tree/92c9de6019fb4896e235a8d9f9453435b830fa10)